# regex string replacement: omit comma if backref is empty

Tags: python, regex, sed, ansible, backreference

I want to use one regex + backref-expression that matches and replaces

`text = 'a,b,c'` with `text = 'a,b,c,item_1'`

`text = ''` with `text = 'item_1'` and

`text = 'a'` with `text = 'a,item_1'`.

1. I am generally interested in solutions using `sed` but also using [python regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).
2. In particular, I am looking for a solution to be used with the [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) module of [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) (python).

Here is what I have so far (in Ansible):

```
regexp:   "^(text[ ]*=[ ]*')([^']*)(')"
backrefs: yes
line:     '\1item_1,\2\3'
```

**Edit:** if possible, the regex + backref-ex pair should ignore an already existing `item_1`, i.e., "replacing"

`text = 'item_1'` with `text = 'item_1'` and

`text = 'a,item_1'` with `text = 'a,item_1'` and

`text = 'a,d,x'` with `text = 'a,item_1,x'`, etc.

Comment: Are a, b and c always single letters, or can it be anything?

Comment: In practice, the items in the list can be real words with underscores, but for this question let's stay with single characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(text[ ]*=[ ]*')((?:[^',]*(,?)[^']*)?[^']*)(')
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/uI2lV7/1) and [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vnPhaN).

```
import re
r = re.compile(r"^(text[ ]*=[ ]*')((?:[^',]*(,?)[^']*)?[^']*)(')")
print(r.sub(r"\1\2\3d\4", "text = 'a,b,c'")) # => text = 'a,b,c,d'
print(r.sub(r"\1\2\3d\4", "text = ''"))      # => text = 'd'
```

What I did is just inserting the `(?:[^',]*(,?)[^']*)?` subpattern to optionally capture a comma. If it is present inside the string, this comma is inserted before `d`. If it is not, no comma is inserted.

**UPDATE**:

You can split the task into two operations:

- Handle all the cases where a vlaue is set: use [`^(text\[ \]*=\[ \]*')(\[^'\]+)(')`](https://regex101.com/r/oS9kL3/1) and replace with `\1\2,d\3`
- And then handle the case with the empty value: use [`^(text\[ \]*=\[ \]*')(')`](https://regex101.com/r/jC0pH0/1) and replace with `\1d\2`.

**Or a Python solution**:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^(text[ ]*=[ ]*\')([^\']*)(\')')
strs = ["text = 'a,b,c'", "text = 'a'", "text = ''"]
print([p.sub(lambda x: x.group(1) + (x.group(2) + ",d" if x.group(2) else "d" ) + x.group(3), s) for s in strs])
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Q4b1CB)

Comment: Thx for this first answer, I tried it and found another case that needs to be covered: replace `text = 'a'` with `text = 'a,d'` (added that to the question)

Comment: There is no way to do it purely with a regex, you need to evaluate the contents of the capture groups. The reason is that you cannot use a conditional replacement pattern in sed or Python `re` regex flavors. Are you interested in the Python code that can handle that case?

Comment: I posted a 2-regex solution that might work for you if you do not have access to direct Python code. I also posted a Python based solution showing how to use a lamda to replace exactly as you want. Not sure it can help.

Comment: Thx for the investigation. I am mostly interested in regex (python-regex) soluitions that can be tested on regex101, as these solutions can be easily ported to ansible. No need for any surrounding python code.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult to do in `sed` (possible in awk) since there is no replace callback feature in sed.

Following callback approach should work in python:

```
import re
reg = re.compile(r"(\btext *= *)'([^']*)'")

def repl(m):
    if len(m.group(2)) == 0:
        return m.group(1) + "'d'";
    else:
        return m.group(1) + "'" + m.group(2) + ",d'"


print(reg.sub(repl, r"text = 'a,b,c'"))
print(reg.sub(repl, r"text = ''"))
print(reg.sub(repl, r"text = 'a'"))
```

**Output:**

```
text = 'a,b,c,d'
text = 'd'
text = 'a,d'
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/0YI96r)

Answer (score 0):

Using a negative look around, I developed a [working solution](https://regex101.com/r/oR2yY3/6) even though it is not perfect:

```
^(text[ ]*=[ ]*)'(((?!item_1[,]?).)*)'
```

This regex grabs all items between the quotes if these does not contain the item to be added (i.e.,`item_1`). The backref-expression then simply adds the missing item:

```
\1'item_1,\2'
```

However, the solution is not perfect as it still results in a trailing comma if the list was empty:

```
text = ''            #text = 'item_1,'
text = 'a'           #text = 'item_1,a'
text = 'a,b,c,d'     #text = 'item_1,a,b,c,d'
```

For my practical case the trailing comma is <strike>not</strike> a problem.
I fixed it by adding another `lineinfile` tasks using [another regex](https://regex101.com/r/bX2fD7/1)

```
regexp:    "^(text[ ]*=[ ]*)'(.*[^,])(,?)'"
backrefs:  yes
line:      "\\1'\\2'"
```